# Receiving [object HTMLInputElement] instead of my Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .js file in the same location as the HTML file and what I am trying to do is when I click on a Radio Button, information displays. I got that working on 4 out of 5 of the buttons. The last one is just displaying the error instead of the Var from the .js file.

```
<p> <!-- Radio buttons for drinks -->
    <strong>Select your drink:</strong>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.drinkList.drinkDesc.value = black" /> Black Coffee
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.drinkList.drinkDesc.value = loco" /> Loco Mocha
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.drinkList.drinkDesc.value = vanilla" /> Vanilla Bean Frappuccino
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.drinkList.drinkDesc.value = pumpkin" /> Pumpkin Spice Latte
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.drinkList.drinkDesc.value = caramel" /> Caramel Macchiato
    <br />
</p>
<p><!-- Design for output -->
    <textarea name="drinkDesc" cols="120" rows="1" style="background-color: Transparent; border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden; font: 16px arial; color: #3F3F3F"></textarea>
</p>
```

And the .js file is just.

```
var black = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans."
var loco = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream."
var vanilla = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)"
var pumpkin = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage."
var caramel = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle."
```

Thank you!

Comment: What error is it displaying?

Comment: is there an input with the id "caramel" in your page?

Comment: [object HTMLInputElement]

Its displaying that instead of the data from the .js file. All of the other Radio Buttons work, except the last one.

Comment: Yes, var caramel is labeled in the .js file I posted.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 The elements with and `id` can be global variables in browsers. So if there is an element with the `id="caramel"` the value of `caramel` would be referring to that element.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Damn I just caught that. I didn't know name="caramel" was included in on that. I got it fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've made 1 change:

used getElementById instead of document.[elementname]

```js
 var black = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans."
var loco = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream."
var vanilla = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)"
var pumpkin = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage."
var caramel = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle."
```

```html
<p> <!-- Radio buttons for drinks -->
                            <strong>Select your drink:</strong>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.getElementById('drinkDesc').value = black" /> Black Coffee
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.getElementById('drinkDesc').value = loco" /> Loco Mocha
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.getElementById('drinkDesc').value = vanilla" /> Vanilla Bean Frappuccino
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.getElementById('drinkDesc').value = pumpkin" /> Pumpkin Spice Latte
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="drink" onclick="document.getElementById('drinkDesc').value = caramel" /> Caramel Macchiato
                            <br />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <!-- Design for output -->
                            <textarea id='drinkDesc' cols="120" rows="1"
                                style="background-color: Transparent; border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden; font: 16px arial;
                                color: #3F3F3F"></textarea>
                        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting `[object HTMLInputElement]` is because the value of `caramel` is referring to an element via being a global variable. Elements in the HTML with an `id` or a `name` could be a global variable to the window in JavaScript. So if an element has `id="caramel"` or `name="caramel"` it will reffer to that element as `caramel` in JS. A simple solution is to use a different name for either the `var caramel` (such as `Caramel`) or change the value of the `id/name` in the HTML element.